# Usage of Fully Connected layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Regarding Fully connected layer, I read that each neuron from the previous layer is connected to the next layer. But.. How does it help?

In general, what's the goal of fully connected layer?

Thank you!

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Purpose of a fully-connected layer", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If all neurons in any layer are connected with any neurons in previous and next layer (if exists) then during learning (changing wages) neural network is able to work on any wages. If some connection doesn't exist then learning process cannot use that one. Exactly the same is when human is learning. Then new connections are build between neurons. It's better to have more connections. It's about posibility to learn, because then wages between these neurons can be modified even to zero.

But sometimes there are neural nets with not fully connected layers, but it has also important usage with different problems solving.